# Troubles with displaying background on Python. Canvas

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, background

```
from tkinter import *

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 950
RAD = 20
SPEED = 30

class mainHero():
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = PhotoImage(file="darth_vader.png")
        self.imageSize = [112,180]
        self.right_side = WIDTH/2+self.imageSize[0]/2
        self.left_side = WIDTH/2-self.imageSize[0]/2
        self.obj = canv.create_image((WIDTH/2,HEIGHT-self.imageSize[0]/2), image = self.image)
    def move(self, event):
        if event.keysym == "Right":
            if self.right_side+SPEED<WIDTH:
                canv.move(self.obj, SPEED, 0)
                self.right_side += SPEED
                self.left_side += SPEED
        if event.keysym == "Left":
            if self.left_side-SPEED>0:
                canv.move(self.obj, -SPEED, 0)
                self.right_side -= SPEED
                self.left_side -= SPEED
        print(self.left_side, self.right_side)

root = Tk()
root.title("YeGame")
root.minsize(width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
root.maxsize(width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
canv = Canvas(root,width =WIDTH,height = HEIGHT, bg="green")
canv.create_rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH%SPEED-1, HEIGHT, fill = "yellow")
canv.create_rectangle(WIDTH-WIDTH%SPEED+1, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, fill = "yellow")
m = canv.create_image((100,100), image = PhotoImage(file="smallnight.gif"))
canv.pack()
canv.focus_set()
me = mainHero()
canv.bind("<KeyPress>", me.move)
root.mainloop()
```

This code should create game. But I don't understand why I can see Darth Vader on Canvas but can't see background of Canvas. It should be image of Space. Code which add Darth Vader works, but code which add background doesn't work. Show me please how I can do it in right way.
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBqlM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image should be declared before calling `create_image` like you did above for mister Vader:

```
root = Tk()
root.title("YeGame")
root.minsize(width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
root.maxsize(width = WIDTH, height = HEIGHT)
canv = Canvas(root,width =WIDTH,height = HEIGHT, bg="green")
canv.create_rectangle(0, 0, WIDTH%SPEED-1, HEIGHT, fill = "yellow")
canv.create_rectangle(WIDTH-WIDTH%SPEED+1, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, fill = "yellow")
background = PhotoImage(file="smallnight.gif")
m = canv.create_image((100,100), image = background)
canv.pack()
canv.focus_set()
me = mainHero()
canv.bind("<KeyPress>", me.move)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I can't understand(we give PhotoImage object in both cases) difference, but thanks, it works)